# Using find() in BeutifulSoup to return desired output from the page

Tags: html, beautifulsoup

I am working on a personal project to locate local health facilities. I am trying to get the names and locations (addresses) from the g maps search results using BS4. However, when I use find_all() to extract the needed information from the soup, nothing is returned. Below is my current code and a picture of the desired output is attached as well. Many thanks for any help in advance. This code below returns match as an empty list ( [] ).

> ```
> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
> import requests
>
> link = "https://www.google.com/maps/search/counselling+center+in+oak+creek/@42.8935355,-87.9406076,13z/data=!3m1!4b1"
>
> page = requests.get(link).text
>
> soup = BeautifulSoup(page,"lxml")
>
> match=soup.find_all("div",{"class":"V0h1Ob-haAclf gd9aEe-LQLjdd OPZbO-KE6vqe"})
>
> print(match)
> ```

Comment: First of all, take a look into the soup - Therein lies the truth.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Any hints? @HedgeHog

Comment: So take a look - Do you see any of expected information in your `soup` ? It is provided dynamically via javascript, so you won't get it with request + beautifulsoup